# Динамическое добавление элементов формы

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Использую следующий код для добавления динамических полей:

```js
$(function()
{
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var buttonadd = '<span><button class="btn btn-success btn-add" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button></span>';
        var fvrhtmlclone = '<div class="fvrclonned">'+$(".fvrduplicate").html()+buttonadd+'</div>';
        $( ".fvrduplicate" ).html(fvrhtmlclone);
        $( ".fvrduplicate" ).after('<div class="fvrclone form-inline"></div>');

        $(document).on('click', '.btn-add', function(e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
    
            $( ".fvrclone" ).append(fvrhtmlclone);
                  $(this).removeClass('btn-add').addClass('btn-remove')
                .removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger')
                .html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>');
            
        }).on('click', '.btn-remove', function(e)
        {
            $(this).parents('.fvrclonned').remove();
    
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
     });

    });
});
```

Для одной формы на странице проблем нет. Но не могу додумать, как быть с несколькими формами - при добавлении поля в одной из них, поле вставляется и в остальные. Предполагаю, что при нажатии кнопки add надо в скрипт передавать id родительского div-блока или формы, но не могу придумать как это сделать...

Заранее спасибо

P.S. HTML формы  -

```html
<div>
<form class="form-horizontal style-form" method="post" id="add_presale_solution_form" name="add_presale_solution_form">    
   <div class="control-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="estimate[][name]" value="Вариант 1">
   </div>
   <br>
   <h4 class="text-left">Смета затрат на подключение</h4>
   <div class="control-group ">   
    <div class="controls form-inline fvrduplicate">
      <label for="name">Наименование</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="estimate[][name]" >
      <label for="quantity">Количество</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="quantity" name="estimate[][quantity]" >
      <label for="total">Итог</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="total" name="estimate[][total]" >
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="control-group">
      <label for="comment">Описание</label>
      <div class="controls">
      <textarea name="comment" id="comment" rows="5" class="form-control" value=""></textarea>
      </div>
   </div> 
   <br>   
   <button id="button" type="button" class="btn btn-round btn-primary"  data-dismiss="modal">Отправить</button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-round btn-default pull-right" data-dismiss="modal">Отмена</button>
  </form>  
  </div>
<div>
<form class="form-horizontal style-form" method="post" id="add_presale_solution_form" name="add_presale_solution_form">    
   <div class="control-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="estimate[][name]" value="Вариант 1">
   </div>
   <br>
   <h4 class="text-left">Смета затрат на подключение</h4>
   <div class="control-group ">   
    <div class="controls form-inline fvrduplicate">
      <label for="name">Наименование</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="estimate[][name]" >
      <label for="quantity">Количество</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="quantity" name="estimate[][quantity]" >
      <label for="total">Итог</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="total" name="estimate[][total]" >
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="control-group">
      <label for="comment">Описание</label>
      <div class="controls">
      <textarea name="comment" id="comment" rows="5" class="form-control" value=""></textarea>
      </div>
   </div> 
   <br>   
   <button id="button" type="button" class="btn btn-round btn-primary"  data-dismiss="modal">Отправить</button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-round btn-default pull-right" data-dismiss="modal">Отмена</button>
  </form>   
</div>
```

Исходники брал с сайта сниппетов bootstrap - http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/XaDoK

Comment: желательно обернуть всё это в анонимную функцию и будет возможность обращаться к каждой форме напрямую минуя выборку по `class\id`

Comment: Немножко не понял... Собственно трудность в том, что в js я не сильно разбираюсь, общее понимание селекторов есть, а вот с реализацией связи между элементами не очень..

Comment: Приведите ваш html-код

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не понял как ваш html-код соотносится с js-кодом, поэтому просто опишу, как получить id родительского блока. (как я понял, затык именно с этим)

Для этого подойдет функция [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/):

Она находит ближайшее совпадение с селектором в родителях элемента:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  parent=$(this).closest('div.search_class');
  console.log(parent.attr('id'))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="find_id" class="search_class">
  <div>
    <button>Check id</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: сайт съел html при вставке pre. Поправил.
Как я понимаю -

Comment: сайт съел html при вставке pre. Поправил.
Как я понимаю - 
1. - запихиваем html код кнопки добавления в buttonadd. 2 - в fvrhtmlclone помещаем div-блок fvrclonned с содержимым блока, данные которого надо скопировать. 3 - меняем содержимое fvrduplicate на fvrhtmlclone. 4 - после fvrduplicate вставляем пустой блок с классом fvrclone. 5 - по нажатию кнопки ищем класс fvrclone и после него вставляем блок  с копированными input. 6 - меняем классы кнопок добавления. Мне следует здесь искать closest('fvrclone'), я правильно понимаю?